# Actual and Formal Argument Lists Differ in Length?

Tags: java, arraylist, comparable

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tester {
   public static void main(String[] args ) {
      ArrayList<Comparable> Aria = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
      Aria.add(new Integer(1));
   }
}
```

Hey Guys. Here is my entire class Tester. I wanted to input an integer into a Comparable ArrayList. However, I am getting an error that states: `method ArrayList.add(int, Comparable) is not applicable (actual and formal arguments differ in lengths of list) method ArrayList.add(Comparable) is not applicable (actual argument Integer cannot be converted to Comparable by method invocation conversion).`

My friend tried this on his PC and it worked without error. THANK YOU FOR HELPING!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want an `ArrayList` of `Comparable`? Do you want a sorted set (`TreeSet<Integer>`)? Otherwise it doesn't really make sense (in my opinion, though there may be a case where it makes sense). You can, after all, not natively compare an `Integer` and a `String` for example (both are `Comparable`). If you want an `ArrayList` of any type of object, just make it `ArrayList<Object>`.

If `Comparable` is not a requirement, just make your definition:

```
ArrayList<Integer> Aria = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparable is a generic type, so

```
ArrayList<Comparable<?>> Aria = new ArrayList<Comparable<?>>();
```